# Google Maps Android API v2: How to make the default POI clickable and get the place detail

Tags: android, google-maps

When using Google Maps Android or iOS API, the map will show some place icons.

I want to know:

1. How to make the places clickable?
2. How to get the place detail? It
   there a google place id?
3. How to disable POI layer?

When using  Google Maps Javascript API, there are also POI on the map. By default, you can click on them, and will show info window of the place. You can also disable the POI layer easily. However, I didn't find any relevant APIs to do that.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I belive this is API which you are looking for: 
https://developers.google.com/places/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google just added this feature in Google Maps Android SDK [v9.6](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#september_21_-_v96).

Now you can register `GoogleMap.OnPoiClickListener` to `GoogleMap` to handle `onPoiClick(PointOfInterest poi)`

Answer (score 1):

It is stated in the [Google Maps object documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#the_map_object) that not all icons on the map are clickable. For example, transit station icons can’t be clicked. However, markers that you add to the map are clickable, and the API has a listener callback interface for various marker interactions.

Now for your problem about Place ID, the Google Places API for Android has a [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) that can help you with it.

Place IDs are available for most locations, including businesses, landmarks, parks, and intersections. These IDs are stable, meaning that once you've identified the place ID for a place, you can reuse that value when you next look up that place. You can use the same place ID across the Google Places API and a number of Google Maps APIs. For more information about Place ID, just check the documentation link above.

I also suggest you to check this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) to know more about how android work with Google Places.

Comment: For the first question, it seems I cannot do it using Google Maps Android/iOS APIs so far. For the Place ID question, I'd like to know how to get the place IDs of those default icons. It also seems not possible so far.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `OnPoiClickListener` does not apply for the POI labels that most of the people click on. The Google Maps iOS SDK supports that, so hopefully this parity gap will be filled on Android in the future!